Map time spent on level based on the date duration pandas python
I have this dataset which has a log of what happened to an issue within given time. I would like to label each status that it went to what level it has been during that time. Im doing it on python using pandas.
EDIT: Adding that each log is tied to a project and I have multiple project with different log. The below example is for 1 project only.



Date
Field
Old Value
New Value




2024-05-16 20:03:00
Status
Development
QA


2024-05-15 01:30:00
Level
3
2


2024-05-14 20:03:00
Status
Work In Progress
Development


2024-05-12 20:03:00
Status
Investigate
Work in Progress


2024-05-08 01:30:00
Level
4
3


2024-05-06 18:57:00
Status
Scrub
Investigate


2024-04-30 00:18:00
Level
N/A
4



This is the output I want:



Date
Field
Old Value
New Value
Level Spent




2024-05-16 20:03:00
Status
Development
QA
2


2024-05-15 01:30:00
Level
3
2
2


2024-05-14 20:03:00
Status
Work In Progress
Development
3


2024-05-12 20:03:00
Status
Investigate
Work in Progress
3


2024-05-08 01:30:00
Level
4
3
3


2024-05-06 18:57:00
Status
Scrub
Investigate
4


2024-04-30 00:18:00
Level
N/A
4
4




Can you explain the expected logic?

IIUC, sort the values by Date, select the values where Field is Level, then ffill:
df['Level Spent'] = (df.sort_values(by='Date')['New Value']
                     .where(df['Field'].eq('Level')).ffill()
                    )

Output:
                  Date   Field         Old Value         New Value Level Spent
0  2024-05-16 20:03:00  Status       Development                QA           2
1  2024-05-15 01:30:00   Level                 3                 2           2
2  2024-05-14 20:03:00  Status  Work In Progress       Development           3
3  2024-05-12 20:03:00  Status       Investigate  Work in Progress           3
4  2024-05-08 01:30:00   Level                 4                 3           3
5  2024-05-06 18:57:00  Status             Scrub       Investigate           4
6  2024-04-30 00:18:00   Level               NaN                 4           4


Hi this work but I have another problem. I forgot to add that I need to tie it up to the project number. Like the table above is 1 project only. I have multiple projects in my dataset. Sorry I forgot to add that

Thank you! This works! I modify it to add sort by Number:
df['Level Spent'] = (df.sort_values(by=['Number', 'Date'])['New Value']                      .where(df['Field'].eq('Level')).ffill()                     )

@Vokult you could also perform this operation in a groupby.
